# Charge of elementary particles

Tags: electrons

For all the particles we know, except for the quarks, so like muon, proton, tau, bosons, neutrino, gluon, Higgs boson ecc. ecc. Is the charge always $q=0,\pm 1$$e$? Does a particle with fractionary electron charge or like $q=2e$ exist? (Except quarks).

Comment: Fractional charge can only be a property of quarks or quasiparticles,- like electrons coupled with magnetic flux quanta in [fractional quantum Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_quantum_Hall_effect). Also you can check some [experimental evidence](https://physicsworld.com/a/fractional-charge-carriers-discovered/) about fractional electric charge in quasiparticles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\Delta^{++}$ Baryon has spin 3/2 and charge $q=+2|e|$. It consist of the three up quarks (q= +2/3|e|)  with parallel spins.